# Use concatenated columns in query with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am creating an api to search users. I am doing this in Eloquent, and I am wondering if there is any way to create a query with Eloquent like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT('first_name', ' ', 'last_name') LIKE '%searchstring%' OR email LIKE '%searchstring%';
```

Is there a way to do this with the Eloquent query builder?

What I would like to do is essentially this:

```
$users = User::where('CONCAT(first_name, " ",last_name)', 'LIKE', '%searchstring%')->orWhere('email','LIKE','%searchstring%')->orderBy($ob, $dir)->paginate($perPage);
```

This results in `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name)' in 'where clause'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer to this question, and the solution was to use the `DB::raw` method around the column name.
The working solution looks like this:

```
$users = User::where(DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name, " ",last_name)'), 'LIKE', '%searchstring%')->orWhere('email','LIKE','%searchstring%')->orderBy($ob, $dir)->paginate($perPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$users = User::where(\DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name, " ",last_name)'), 'LIKE', '%searchstring%')->orWhere('email','LIKE','%searchstring%')->orderBy($ob, $dir)->paginate($perPage);
```